# Delta Bathtub Faucet - Unaligned handle stopper

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet

I have a newly installed delta bathtub faucet, however, the person who did the job was a bit sloppy. Now the handle is not aligned.

I tried to take the screw off the handle, however, the handle installation piece looks like it has some sort of dummy prevention pattern that only allows the handle to be installed a specific way.

[image][image]

Is there any way to repair this? I can probably take the bonnet nut (Part RP60352) off and try to adjust the Valve assembly (Part RP60400)?

A documentation on the faucet: [Delta Faucet](http://media.deltafaucet.com/MandI/77528%20Rev%20C.pdf)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is adjust the end valve nut based on the screw position of the valve handles.

> 1 > A > 4: Note: End valves may be rotated to align handles and stops before
>   tightening nuts.

[image]

Comment: Does this mean I need to take apart the bathtub? Number 4 is hidden.

Comment: With one exception... You can take off the handle and put a cloth over the valve and see if you can use channel locks or vice grip pliers, to turn it counterclockwise. It may work since you are attempting to rotate it in a loosening direction.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. I think I need to get the plumber to fix it. This sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: @user1157751 I would try that first as well :) Not to question how you react but I would try to fake the request with some kindness at first for possible fast and pleasant results :P

Comment: Ohh I know :), getting pissed off just makes life miserable for me and the plumber.

Comment: @user1157751  I know what you mean.. that is why I usually have the wife call first.  I say to myself,  stay calm but then if, well you get the idea :P Good luck with this, cheers.

Comment: Haha, I'll try to keep my cool. Thanks a bunch for your help! :D